# WkHtmlToPdf Google Maps

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Running a command like...

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe https://maps.google.com goog.pdf
```

Renders the page with no map in the background.  What are the secret command line options to get it to render with the map?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also take a look at Google Static Maps for PDFs. Essentially just generates an image that can more easily be embedded in a PDF.

Answer (score 2):

```
--javascript-delay 3000
```

May be what your looking for.